# Keeping image full size even when resized

Tags: css

I have a background image of dimensions 1903x2160.

Is there a way to prevent the scaling or resizing of this background image when the window is resized? I'd like to have the image centered horizontally and to just crop out (so to speak) the sides of the image in order to keep the image exactly in place when it is resized.

I figured that something like this (grabbed off of this website) would work, but it doesn't since it just seems to want to make the background image in full view vertically no matter what:

```
html { 
  background: url(http://lolcat.com/images/lolcats/1338.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: auto 100%;
  -moz-background-size: auto 100%;
  -o-background-size: auto 100%;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  }
```

Comment: Aha, so basically when you resize the window you want the image to be perfectly still - but cropped at the same time by the window area

Comment: Might be a good idea to [read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) of the property you're trying to manipulate. That way you'll understand it next time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can explicitly declare the size of the background so it won't resize.

```
html { 
  background: url(http://lolcat.com/images/lolcats/1338.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: 1903px 2160px;
  -moz-background-size: 1903px 2160px;
  -o-background-size: 1903px 2160px;
  background-size: 1903px 2160px;
  }
```

Comment: This was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, the 'cover' directive is what is making it rescale.

```
  html {
  background: url("https://c1.staticflickr.com/8/7271/7721541330_9fb7620608_h.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  }
```